# Use declare styleable to set custom component input type

Tags: android, custom-component, attr

I have a CompositeComponent (EditText+ImageButton)
When clicking on button the edittext content will be cleared.
It is working fine. My problem is setting attributes to my component. I am using declare-styleable to set attributes to my component.

I am successful at setting minLines, maxLines and textColor.

How can I set inputtype to my component via xml.

my attributes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="CET">
        <attr name="MaxLines" format="integer"/>
        <attr name="MinLines" format="integer"/>
        <attr name="TextColor" format="color"/>
        <attr name="InputType" format="integer" />
        <attr name="Hint" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

And usage of mycomponent in main_layout.xml:

```
<com.test.ui.ClearableEditText
        xmlns:cet="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.test.ui"
        android:id="@+id/clearableEditText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        cet:MaxLines="2"
        cet:MinLines="1"
        cet:TextColor="#0000FF"
        cet:InputType="" <---I cant set this property--------->
        cet:Hint="Clearable EditText Hint">

    </com.test.ui.ClearableEditText>
```

Ordinary Edittext usage:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" <--------I want to use this property--------> >
```

I cant use ENUM in my attribute.xml.
How to refer `android:inputType="numberSigned"` in my  `cet:InputType`?

**EDIT:**

This is how I assign properties in my ClearableEditText.java

```
TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,R.styleable.CET,0, 0);

            int minLines = a.getInt(R.styleable.CET_MinLines, 1);
            int maxLines = a.getInt(R.styleable.CET_MaxLines, 100);
            String hint = a.getString(R.styleable.CET_Hint);
            int textColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.CET_TextColor, Color.BLACK);
            int inputType = a.getInt(R.styleable.CET_InputType, -108);

            Log.i(TAG, "ClearableEditText: Min Line "+minLines +" Max Lines: "+maxLines+" Hint "+hint+" Color: "+textColor+" Input Type: "+inputType);

            edit_text.setMaxLines(maxLines);
            edit_text.setMinLines(minLines);
            edit_text.setTextColor(textColor);
            edit_text.setHint(hint);
            if(inputType != -108)
                edit_text.setInputType(inputType);
```

You can see there is no problem with assigning the inputType property to editText.

Comment: I didn't get any error. Its working fine. I don't know how to assign the input type?? instead of giving raw integer value I want to use the enum (android:inputtype) in android.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Lets say you have a custom view named InputView, which is not a TextView (lets say its a RelativeLayout).

In your attrs.xml:

```
<declare-styleable name="InputView">

    <!-- any custom attributes -->
    <attr name="title" format="string" /> 

    <!-- standart attributes, note android: prefix and no format attribute -->
    <attr name="android:imeOptions"/> 
    <attr name="android:inputType"/>

</declare-styleable>
```

In an xml layout where you want to include InputView:

```
<!-- note xmlns:custom and com.mycompany.myapp -->
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <!-- note that you will be using android: prefix for standart attributes, and not custom: prefix -->
        <!-- also note that you can use standart values: actionNext or textEmailAddress -->
        <com.mycompany.myapp.InputView
        android:id="@+id/emailField"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        custom:title="@string/my_title"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext|flagNoExtractUi"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Inside your custom class you can extract attributes as usual:

```
    ...

    private String title;
    private int inputType;
    private int imeOptions;

    ...
    TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.InputView);

    int n = a.getIndexCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int attr = a.getIndex(i);
        switch (attr) {
        case R.styleable.InputView_title:
            title = a.getString(attr);
            break;
        //note that you are accessing standart attributes using your attrs identifier
        case R.styleable.InputView_android_inputType:
            inputType = a.getInt(attr, EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL);
            break;
        case R.styleable.InputView_android_imeOptions:
            imeOptions = a.getInt(attr, 0);
            break;
        default:
            Log.d("TAG", "Unknown attribute for " + getClass().toString() + ": " + attr);
            break;
        }
    }

    a.recycle();
    ...
```

Comment: I know this is a very old post but I was wondering if there is a way to make eclipse display the suggestions like it does for an edittext?

Comment: I wasn't able to make eclipse show suggestions. Maybe it'll work in the future updates of adt.

Comment: Does this Code work ? Because i did everything as is written here but in my custom class I can't get inputType attribute. can't resolve this line: case R.styleable.InputView_android_inputType:

Comment: Check that attrs.xml contains <attr name="android:inputType"/> tag inside InputView element and that you import your own R file, not android.R file.

Comment: @Alexey: We need more SO answers like the one you posted above. Well done! clear, concise, no BS, straight to the point and helpful.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Just a small note: I had to use `EditorInfo.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT` instead of `EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL` as default value.

Answer (score 5):

use this in your attr.xml for the suggestions . the use of flags give the suggestions in xml while using edittext.
the custom:inputType="text"
and it will suggest you the addition types.
to add more flags use this link
Visit https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/attrs.xml

```
<resources>

<declare-styleable name="ClearableEditText">
    <attr name="hintText" format="string" />
    <attr name="inputType" format="integer">

        <!-- There is no content type. The text is not editable. -->
        <flag name="none" value="0x00000000" />
        <!--
Just plain old text. Corresponds to
{@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_CLASS_TEXT} |
{@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL}.
        -->
        <flag name="text" value="0x00000001" />
        <!--
Can be combined with <var>text</var> and its variations to
request capitalization of all characters. Corresponds to
{@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS}.
        -->
    </attr>
  </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I know this question is pretty old but I found the REAL correct answer.

I found the attrs.xml file in [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/2888524e03896831f487e5dee63f18f1c33c0115/core/res/res/values/attrs.xml#869) that Android uses and every declare_styleable is there, so from the standard attributes you can find the inputType attribute that is defined as below

```
<!-- The type of data being placed in a text field used to help an
         input method decide how to let the user enter text.  The constants
         here correspond to those defined by
         {@link android.text.InputType}.  Generally you can select
         a single value, though some can be combined together as
         indicated.  Setting this attribute to anything besides
         <var>none</var> also implies that the text is editable. -->
    <attr name="inputType">
        <!-- There is no content type.  The text is not editable. -->
        <flag name="none" value="0x00000000" />
        <!-- Just plain old text.  Corresponds to
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_CLASS_TEXT} |
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL}. -->
        <flag name="text" value="0x00000001" />
        <!-- Can be combined with <var>text</var> and its variations to
             request capitalization of all characters.  Corresponds to
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS}. -->
        <flag name="textCapCharacters" value="0x00001001" />
        <!-- Can be combined with <var>text</var> and its variations to
             request capitalization of the first character of every word.  Corresponds to
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS}. -->
        <flag name="textCapWords" value="0x00002001" />
        <!-- Can be combined with <var>text</var> and its variations to
             request capitalization of the first character of every sentence.  Corresponds to
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES}. -->
        <flag name="textCapSentences" value="0x00004001" />
        <!-- Can be combined with <var>text</var> and its variations to
             request auto-correction of text being input.  Corresponds to
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_CORRECT}. -->
        <flag name="textAutoCorrect" value="0x00008001" />
        <!-- Can be combined with <var>text</var> and its variations to
             specify that this field will be doing its own auto-completion and
             talking with the input method appropriately.  Corresponds to
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_COMPLETE}. -->
        <flag name="textAutoComplete" value="0x00010001" />
        <!-- Can be combined with <var>text</var> and its variations to
             allow multiple lines of text in the field.  If this flag is not set,
             the text field will be constrained to a single line.  Corresponds to
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE}. -->
        <flag name="textMultiLine" value="0x00020001" />
        <!-- Can be combined with <var>text</var> and its variations to
             indicate that though the regular text view should not be multiple
             lines, the IME should provide multiple lines if it can.  Corresponds to
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_IME_MULTI_LINE}. -->
        <flag name="textImeMultiLine" value="0x00040001" />
        <!-- Can be combined with <var>text</var> and its variations to
             indicate that the IME should not show any
             dictionary-based word suggestions.  Corresponds to
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS}. -->
        <flag name="textNoSuggestions" value="0x00080001" />
        <!-- Text that will be used as a URI.  Corresponds to
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_CLASS_TEXT} |
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_URI}. -->
        <flag name="textUri" value="0x00000011" />
        <!-- Text that will be used as an e-mail address.  Corresponds to
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_CLASS_TEXT} |
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS}. -->
        <flag name="textEmailAddress" value="0x00000021" />
        <!-- Text that is being supplied as the subject of an e-mail.  Corresponds to
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_CLASS_TEXT} |
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_SUBJECT}. -->
        <flag name="textEmailSubject" value="0x00000031" />
        <!-- Text that is the content of a short message.  Corresponds to
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_CLASS_TEXT} |
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_SHORT_MESSAGE}. -->
        <flag name="textShortMessage" value="0x00000041" />
        <!-- Text that is the content of a long message.  Corresponds to
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_CLASS_TEXT} |
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_LONG_MESSAGE}. -->
        <flag name="textLongMessage" value="0x00000051" />
        <!-- Text that is the name of a person.  Corresponds to
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_CLASS_TEXT} |
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PERSON_NAME}. -->
        <flag name="textPersonName" value="0x00000061" />
        <!-- Text that is being supplied as a postal mailing address.  Corresponds to
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_CLASS_TEXT} |
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_POSTAL_ADDRESS}. -->
        <flag name="textPostalAddress" value="0x00000071" />
        <!-- Text that is a password.  Corresponds to
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_CLASS_TEXT} |
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD}. -->
        <flag name="textPassword" value="0x00000081" />
        <!-- Text that is a password that should be visible.  Corresponds to
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_CLASS_TEXT} |
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD}. -->
        <flag name="textVisiblePassword" value="0x00000091" />
        <!-- Text that is being supplied as text in a web form.  Corresponds to
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_CLASS_TEXT} |
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_EDIT_TEXT}. -->
        <flag name="textWebEditText" value="0x000000a1" />
        <!-- Text that is filtering some other data.  Corresponds to
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_CLASS_TEXT} |
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_FILTER}. -->
        <flag name="textFilter" value="0x000000b1" />
        <!-- Text that is for phonetic pronunciation, such as a phonetic name
             field in a contact entry.  Corresponds to
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_CLASS_TEXT} |
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PHONETIC}. -->
        <flag name="textPhonetic" value="0x000000c1" />
        <!-- Text that will be used as an e-mail address on a web form.  Corresponds to
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_CLASS_TEXT} |
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_EMAIL_ADDRESS}. -->
        <flag name="textWebEmailAddress" value="0x000000d1" />
        <!-- Text that will be used as a password on a web form.  Corresponds to
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_CLASS_TEXT} |
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_PASSWORD}. -->
        <flag name="textWebPassword" value="0x000000e1" />
        <!-- A numeric only field.  Corresponds to
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER} |
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_NORMAL}. -->
        <flag name="number" value="0x00000002" />
        <!-- Can be combined with <var>number</var> and its other options to
             allow a signed number.  Corresponds to
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER} |
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED}. -->
        <flag name="numberSigned" value="0x00001002" />
        <!-- Can be combined with <var>number</var> and its other options to
             allow a decimal (fractional) number.  Corresponds to
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER} |
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL}. -->
        <flag name="numberDecimal" value="0x00002002" />
        <!-- A numeric password field.  Corresponds to
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER} |
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD}. -->
        <flag name="numberPassword" value="0x00000012" />
        <!-- For entering a phone number.  Corresponds to
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_CLASS_PHONE}. -->
        <flag name="phone" value="0x00000003" />
        <!-- For entering a date and time.  Corresponds to
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME} |
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_DATETIME_VARIATION_NORMAL}. -->
        <flag name="datetime" value="0x00000004" />
        <!-- For entering a date.  Corresponds to
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME} |
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_DATETIME_VARIATION_DATE}. -->
        <flag name="date" value="0x00000014" />
        <!-- For entering a time.  Corresponds to
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME} |
             {@link android.text.InputType#TYPE_DATETIME_VARIATION_TIME}. -->
        <flag name="time" value="0x00000024" />
    </attr>
```

So you have 2 choices, if you need to change the name of inputType to another name (i.e title_inputType) then you need to copy all of this over, but if you need to keep the same name, then use [Alexey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10361617/5209185)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it with raw int value:
I think it is not good practice.
I can assign raw values like this: `cet:InputType="2"`

2 for number (Referred for values: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#TextView_inputType)

I believe  `<attr name="InputType" format="reference" />` can help but don't know how to use it.