# Hint and InputType on Included EditText

Tags: android, include, android-edittext

I have a custom `EditText` declared in an XML file and I'm including it like so:

```
<include layout="@layout/my_edit_text"
        android:id="@+id/passwordField"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/passwordHint"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />
```

and here is `my_edit_text.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:textColor="@color/gray"
    android:textSize="@dimen/editTextFontSize"
    android:padding="@dimen/editTextPadding"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"
    android:ellipsize="end" />
```

However, I can't set the `hint` or `inputType` this way, for some reason. If I set it in `my_edit_text.xml`, it works fine, but I would like to be able to set each reference individually.

The reason that I have the custom `EditText` is to avoid having to rewrite all of the common values in every one of my `EditText`s.

Do I have to do something similar to [what this person has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732705/use-declare-styleable-to-set-custom-component-input-type)? If I do, will I need to actually build a .java subclass and extract the attributes that way? That just seems excessive.

Comment: Your my_edit_text layout probably has a group like LinearLayout, so you can't set the hint because LinearLayout doesn't have hint. You can get the EditText in java and set the hint and inputType.

Comment: @nininho It does not, but I like that we're thinking. Thank you!

Comment: Please post `my_edit_text.xml` and explain why it exists in the first place (what are you hoping to accomplish by having it?). Then we may be able to help you find a replacement approach for `my_edit_text.xml` that addresses your issues.

Comment: @CommonsWare I've added it and the explanation (Second paragraph after code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The reason that I have the custom EditText is to avoid having to rewrite all of the common values in every one of my EditTexts.

Step #1: Delete `my_edit_text.xml`.

Step #2: Delete all references to `my_edit_text.xml`.

Step #3: Define a style resource (e.g., in `res/values/styles.xml`) akin to:

```
<style name="rileyText">
  <item name="android:textColor">@color/gray</item>
  <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/editTextFontSize</item>
  <item name="android:padding">@dimen/editTextPadding</item>
  <item name="android:background">@drawable/edit_text_background</item>
  <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
</style>
```

Step #4: Add `style="@style/rileyText"` to all `EditText` widgets that you want to have those particular attributes applied to.

Comment: And this is why you're awesome. Thank you! I am just trying to learn all of the proper Android coding practices and this is excellent!

Comment: @RileyE: Sorry that your proposed edit was rejected -- I have fixed the answer.

Comment: As long as the edit is made, it will be perfect for future coders. Thanks again.