# Reusing 'inputType' attribute from TextView in custom view

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, android-custom-view, android-attributes

I'm trying to reuse the 'android:inputType' attribute from TextView in my custom view, but the error I get is:

> String types not allowed (at 'inputType' with value 'textMultiline').

I have referred to the solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/10361617/313042

The attr file contains:

```
<declare-styleable name="MyEditText">
    <attr name="android:inputType"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

The MyEditText.java is:

```
int n = typedArray.getIndexCount();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int attr = typedArray.getIndex(i);

    switch (attr) {
        case R.styleable.MyEditText_android_inputType:
            inputTypes = typedArray.getInt(attr, EditorInfo.TYPE_NULL);
            break;

    }
}
```

and the layout file contains:

```
<com.example.MyEditText
  android:id="@+id/met"
  style="@style/MyStyle"
  android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
  android:inputType="textMultiline" />
```

Is there any way I can solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: You only need to declare new attributes

Comment: @NickCardoso , do you mean i shouldn't declare: <attr name="android:inputType"/>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your typo `textMultiline` must be `textMultiLine`.

Please see supported `android:inputType` via xml in [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType)

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you. Would have taken a long time to figure this one out.

Comment: Yeah. Sometime, I thought how beautiful it is if IDE can support us to detect typo (just kidding).

Comment: Well, it's not such a bad idea - Google can introduce a warning for this - something like "Did you mean textMultiLine?" built into Android Studio.